# siebel fat client stuck in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, crm, windows-7-x64, siebel, fat-client

I'm using Siebel 8.1.1.14 on windows 7 64 bit and using IE8 32bit, Fat and local clients were working fine but suddenly when I tried to reopen them the IE8 says website is found but progress after a while is stuck and doesn't show Siebel page and thin client is working fine, I have tried to reinstall Siebel but it was the same problem, any ideas or solution.

Comment: Have you checked your siebel.log file? Actually, before that: is the siebel.log file created every time you try to start it, or it doesn't even reach that point? Also, does the Siebel icon appear in the Windows system tray?

Answer (score 1):

Please check the log file , if you are using Siebel Power Communications, it should be called eCommunications_lan_somenumber.log

Lan= language code, enu for english
somenumber is a random siebel generated number.

You can check the logfile name in table s_srm_task_hist where srvr_login_name = your login name in Siebel.

You can check all the IE hanging issues here
http://www.eir.me/siebel.php?art_id=126&cat=1

You should also check all your IE settings here

http://www.eir.me/siebel.php?art_id=91&cat=1

Please also check if you have installed any plugins or security settings in IE